# Sed for partial replacement?

Tags: sed, awk, gawk

Imagine I have a file that has the following type of line:

FIXED_DATA1 VARIABLE_DATA FIXED_DATA2

I want to change the fixed data and leave the variable data as is. *For various reasons*, using two sed operations to replace the fixed data will not work. For instance, the fixed fields might be double-quotes, and the line has other areas containing them, thus really the regex is written to match a pattern in the variable data and the fixed data.

If I'm bent on using sed, is there a way to change both fixed data fields at once while leaving the variable field unchanged?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to partition the line into the three pieces, replace the outer two and leave the middle alone:

```
sed 's/^FIX1 \(.*\) FIX2$/New \1 End/'
```

You can make the beginning and end matches more complex as needed.

Comment: +1 the capturing parentheses and `\1` backreference is the key.